# Animated show about a little boy who could travel to different places

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv, animated-series

The start would always either be the little boy on his bike or playing. He would travel to different places. One place was Canada and he helped drive a train and gave different people syrup. Another place was he went to went visit Narwhals or he went and drove horse carts. I’ve been looking for this show for forever. The little boy had brown hair and was always traveling with someone else.

Comment: You used the [time-travel] tag for this question, so did the boy explicitly travel through time? If so, how? And what time period was he from originally? Also in roughly which year did you watch this, and was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Answer (score 8):

Is this ***[Justin Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1870073/)*** (2011–2017)...?

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Time_(TV_series)), it's an animated series about a boy named Justin who has "adventures through time and around the world," alongside his shape-shifting sidekick, Squidgy. Their best friend, Olive, also appears in each episode.

> *Justin Time* is a Canadian animated television series created by Brandon James Scott and developed by Frank Falcone, Mary Bredin, and James Scott. The series premiered on September 22, 2011, with the finale airing on June 24, 2016. A total of 76 segments in 39 episodes were produced. This show was made for Disney Junior in Canada.
>
> [...]
>
> **The series revolves around the adventures of Justin. In every episode, Justin encounters a problem of everyday childhood (such as sharing, teamwork, or paying attention). Then, Justin and his shape-shifting sidekick Squidgy solve the problems by tackling them in adventures through time and around the world.** In every adventure, Justin and Squidgy meet their best friend Olive, who always lives in the place and time they are visiting, and who usually needs their help to accomplish a task. Together, the three of them encounter the same problem that Justin faces in his world, and together they solve the problem before he gets called back by his parents to his world.
>
> In the original concept, Justin travelled via a time machine, which led to the title "Justin Time". Because the concept of "the past" is challenging for preschoolers, the TV series instead focuses on more developmentally appropriate adventures of fun.

According to the [IMDB episode guide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1870073/episodes/?ref_=tt_ov_epl), a segment in S01E11 titled "[The Pancake Express](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2407762/?ref_=ttep_ep11)" involves Justin and Squidgy driving a steam train through the Canadian wilderness with a barrel full of maple syrup as their cargo.

> 'All aboard!' **Justin and Squidgy are driving a steam train that chugs through the Canadian wilderness. Olive joins them and loads the train with some very important cargo - a barrel full of maple syrup** for the Pancake Festival in Flapjack Falls! Justin, Olive and Squidgy face challenges along the journey, but Justin is determined to deliver their cargo on time!

A segment in S02E05 titled "[The Northwest Shortcut](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5568626/?ref_=ttpl_ov)" involves Justin, Olive and Squidgy helping a narwhal tangled in seaweed while journeying to the Northwest Passage.

> The Northwest Shortcut - The The sea is freezing over. **Justin, Olive and Squidgy are in a hurry to find the Northwest Passage but they take some time to help a narwhal tangled in some seaweed. The thankful narwhal comes back later to return the favor when the ship gets stuck.**

Justin evidently has brown hair, judging by the opening below.